# Can a creature benefit twice from an alignment-specific soulmeld?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, meldshaping

If a creature takes the feat Shape Soulmeld (*Magic of Incarnum* 40) so it can shape a soulmeld that expects to be shaped by a creature possessing a *lone* alignment component, does the creature gain *both* components' benefits if the creature's the appropriate alignment?

That is, the soulmelds *incarnate avatar* (*MoI* 71-2) and *planar chasuble* (*MoI* 83) are usually available only to incarnates—who are restricted to the alignments CN, LN, NE, and NG—, yet a CE, CG, LE, or LG creature could shape those soulmelds *via* the feat Shape Soulmeld. Does such a creature receive the soulmeld's benefit based on *both* alignment components the creature possesses?

---

***Note:*** I'm considering the feat Shape Soulmeld picking incarnate avatar *and the* Magic of Incarnum *feat Open Soul Chakra (213) for a an upcoming session's big bad. It seems a shame for the LE bad guy to shape and bind the soulmeld* incarnate avatar *and, in exchange for having to do without armor, only get* either *the immunities* or *the flight.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ambiguous

This is a question that comes up often in discussions of *Magic of Incarnum*, and there just is no solid, credible, certain answer. The text itself could go either way (for that matter, *planar chausible* refers to incarnates specifically, which makes one wonder what happens when a non-incarnate shapes it).

Either allowing the double-dip, or forcing an LG/CG/LE/CE character to pick one at some point (when taking the feat or when shaping the soulmeld) both work fine. If you allow the double-dip, it makes sense (to me, anyway) to houserule a feat that allows incarnates to “count as” one of the alignments they are neutral to for the purposes of these soulmelds—if anyone else can double-dip with a feat, so too should incarnates.